# How to remove data that was pushed in a list in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Given

```
var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/message_list');
    messageListRef.push({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });
```

How to remove that added data `{ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' }` later from Firebase? Is there a clean and simple way to do that?

I would like to be able to find that data again later and then remove it, assuming I don't know the unique id generated, I can't do `new Firebase('https://SampleChat.firebaseIO-demo.com/message_list/'+uniqueId).remove()` (and I don't know if this is the good practice). In my idea I would first query the data but I don't know how I can do that with a list of data. For example, I would like to be able to remove that data onDisconnect.

On that page https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html, it seems the "See Lists of Data" is not yet written. Is it in the roadmap to add such remove for lists of data?

Comment: See Lists of Data is probably meant to point at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push

Answer (score 3):

When you call `push` it returns the new node. So you could keep a list of messages the user added in memory:

```
var myMessageKeys = []; // put this somewhere "globally"
```

And then whenever you add a message:

```
var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push({ 'user_id': 'fred', 'text': 'Yabba Dabba Doo!' });
myMessageKeys.push(newMessageRef.key());
```

Personally this feels hacky to me. I would prefer to use a query, so that for example if fred disconnects you'd do something like:

```
var myMessages = messageListRef.orderByChild('user_id').equalTo('fred');
myMessages.on('value', function(messagesSnapshot) {
    messagesSnapshot.forEach(function(messageSnapshot) {
        messageSnapshot.ref().remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So figuring out which messages to remove is the trick. But suppose you want to delete by user id; perhaps when `Fred` disconnects, you want to remove all of his messages. You could find and delete them like this:

```
var query = messageListRef.orderByChild('user_id').equalTo('Fred');

query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach( function(msg) {
        msg.ref().remove();
    });
});
```